# Whole-System Snapshot on Operating System

Tags: linux, snapshot

I need a whole-system snapshot( both system state and disk ) on Linux.

I know that there are several ways to take disk snapshot such as lvm2, zfs, or Btrfs.
However, I could not look for any whole-system snapshot (cpu, memory, and disk state) anywhere. Is there any way to do that? I mean the way like system snapshot feature on VM.

Comment: Hibernation is doing a whole system snapshot somehow. But why do you ask?

Comment: You mean "Take Hibernation -> Boot with lvm2 snapshot -> rollback to hibernation with normal boot" ? I think it can work, but it cannot have the same app status. Or, can I copy and edit the hibernation file directly to point my snapshot partition and reboot it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to take a snapshot of the entire system from within the system -- doing so would pose some rather difficult questions -- but you can take a snapshot of a subset of the processes in a Linux system using the [cgroup freezer system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/freezer-subsystem.txt). Alternatively, you can take a snapshot of an entire OpenVZ guest (under a VZ kernel) using [vzdump](http://wiki.openvz.org/Backup_of_a_running_container_with_vzdump).

Note that neither of these will include a snapshot of your filesystem. You'd have to do that separately, using one of the methods you mentioned.

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the cgroup freezer system is down. Link to the archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20141108014201/https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/freezer-subsystem.txt

Comment: Not gone, just moved. I've updated the link.